# setInterval runs node function once and continues to run but does not run function

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

I have a node process running that calls a node module

```
var monitor = require('./monitor.js');

var monitorInterval = setInterval(function () {
    monitor();
    console.log('running monitor')
}, 10000);
```

The first time this runs the monitor module but it then seems to run the interval but not the function on each subsequent 10s interval. The logs look like this.

```
MONITOR PROCESS STARTING
running monitor
running monitor
database connected
database connected
etc...

running monitor
running monitor

running monitor
running monitor
<10s PASS AND MONITOR DOES NOT RUN HERE>

running monitor
running monitor
<10s PASS MONITOR DOES NOT RUN HERE>
```

So why is this? Could it be because the JS engine is not idle? I'm pretty sure it is doing nothing during subsequent intervals.

Monitor is initialized as follows:

```
function Monitor() {
    this._initialize();
}

module.exports = function (cb) {
    if (monitor === null) {
        monitor = new Monitor();
    }
};

Monitor.prototype = {

    _initialize: function () {
        console.log('MONITOR PROCESS STARTING');
        var monitor = this;
//etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to return the monitor value/instance inside the module exports?

Comment: What is the desired behavior? Do you want to instantiate a new `Monitor` class every time through the interval? You seem to be looking for the `MONITOR PROCESS STARTING` message, which will be output only when upon instantiation. But in that case, what is the meaning of the check of the `monitor` variable, which, by the way, seems to never have been initialized.

Comment: In all honesty, I copied this code from another node module so I don't really know what the purpose of the `monitor` check is. I suppose it was originally meant to prevent the class from be instantiated twice.

I want to instantiate a new `Monitor` class every time through the interval.

Comment: `monitor` is actually instantiated in the initialize class (see edit above) so you've answered my question - the class is instantiated only once because of this check. Thanks.